# Is it possible to use `lualatex`'s DVI output with `fontspec` without getting font-related errors?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, eps, dvi-mode, sagetex

Is it possible to use `lualatex`'s DVI output with `fontspec` without getting font-related errors?  I want to use the (eps-based) output of `sagetex` with a `lualatex` generated document with `fontspec`. As `sagetex` uses eps graphics, the only way I can use it in a document is if I use `lualatex`'s DVI output. As I **also** want to use `fontspec` with it (to load Helvetica and use that as the font for text in my document), can I get lualatex to produce DVI output that is compatible with `fontspec`.

Comment: The DVI format doesn't support OpenType fonts. With the `epstopdf` package you can use EPS also with direct PDF output.

Comment: No. There is no driver which can process such a dvi. Use epstopdf to convert your eps graphics to pdf.

Answer (score 4):

If I compile this file with `dvilualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Some test
\end{document}
```

the response of `dvitype` is

```
This is DVItype, Version 3.6 (TeX Live 2016)
Options selected:
  Starting page = * 
  Maximum number of pages = 1000000
  Output level = 4 (the works)
  Resolution = 300.00000000 pixels per inch
numerator/denominator=25400000/473628672
magnification=1000;       0.00006334 pixels per DVI unit
' LuaTeX output 2017.02.05:0007'
Postamble starts at byte 173.
maxv=41484288, maxh=26673152, maxstackdepth=3, totalpages=1
Font 14: [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;---not loaded, TFM file can't be opened! 

45: beginning of page 1 
90: push 
level 0:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
91: push 
level 1:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
92: push 
level 2:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
93: right3 5046272 h:=0+5046272=5046272, hh:=320 
[ ]
97: down3 4128768 v:=0+4128768=4128768, vv:=262 
101: fntdef1 14: [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;---this font wasn't loaded before!
---not loaded, TFM file can't be opened! 
143: fntnum14 invalid font selection: font 14 was never defined! current font is UNDEFINED! 
144: setchar83 character 83 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5046272+0=5046272, hh:=320 
145: setchar111 character 111 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5046272+0=5046272, hh:=320 
146: setchar109 character 109 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5046272+0=5046272, hh:=320 
147: setchar101 character 101 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5046272+0=5046272, hh:=320 
148: right3 218235 h:=5046272+218235=5264507, hh:=333 
152: setchar116 character 116 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5264507+0=5264507, hh:=333 
153: setchar101 character 101 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5264507+0=5264507, hh:=333 
154: setchar115 character 115 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5264507+0=5264507, hh:=333 
155: setchar116 character 116 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=5264507+0=5264507, hh:=333 
[Some test]
156: pop 
level 2:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
157: pop 
level 1:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
158: push 
level 1:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
159: right4 15204352 h:=0+15204352=15204352, hh:=963 
[ ]
164: down4 41484288 v:=0+41484288=41484288, vv:=2628 
169: setchar49 character 49 invalid in font UNDEFINED! h:=15204352+0=15204352, hh:=963 
[1]
170: pop 
level 1:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
171: pop 
level 0:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
172: eop
```

As you see, it is written out, but no sensible information can be derived from it. In particular, `dvips` is not able to cope with OpenType fonts and there is no DVI driver which can, at the moment.

On the other hand, converting EPS files to PDF is quite easy: TeX Live (also MiKTeX) provide the `epstopdf` script for the purpose and compiling with `lualatex` will do the conversion on the fly.